# Strange power comsuption into sleep mode

Tags: power, led, arduino-pro-mini

I've finished my project and now I'm measuring the current but there is something wrong. I'm using an Arduino Pro Mini board and the [LowPower](https://github.com/rocketscream/Low-Power) library but the consumption is about **3.5 - 5 mA** and not less than 500 uA (the board remains into sleep mode almost all the time).

When I began to work with the board its LED was removed but I think that this work was not made correctly. How can I check that LED was removed correctly?

Thanks to all.

**EDIT1:** **The strange power consumption is not associated with board's LED.**

**EDIT2:** [@Gerben](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users/2881/gerben) has suggested me to review the state of SPI pins connected to the board. I use in this project a SD card module and GSM/GPRS module but the guilty of this excessive power consumption is the first. Then I've disconnected all SD card module's pins and then I get about **60 uA**, so the problem is on those pins but I can't reduce the power consumption. SD card module pins are 10,11,12 and 13 so I've used statements like `digitalWrite(10, LOW)`, `digitalWrite(11, LOW)` and so on after reading/writing on the SD card but it is useless.

**EDIT3:** I've decided to upload a representation of my project using Fritzing. The external modules are not identical but they contain the same pins.

General view of the circuit:[image: general view of the circuit].

Detail of the connections:

[image: more detail]

I use these external components:

- [SD card module](https://www.elecfreaks.com/wiki/index.php?title=SD%26MMC_Card_Module_Double_Side)
- [A6 GPRS/GSM module](http://www.dx.com/es/p/open-smart-gprs-a6-pro-serial-gprs-gsm-module-core-developemnt-board-439972?tc=EUR&gclid=CLnm75W0_tECFYUp0wodeeQD6Q#.WJn2D_Ja3SA)

In my project there are some important details:

- GPRS module is powered individually. The other battery is dedicated to power on the Arduino board and the SD card module.
- Batteries are 6v.
- Transistors base are controlled by 2 and 3 digital pins respectively.
- The 8 and 9 pins of the Arduino board act like RX and TX pins using `AltSofSerial.h` library.

Comment: See [Power saving techniques for microprocessors](http://gammon.com.au/power) for some tips. I doubt it is anything to do with the non-existent LED.

Comment: How would you remove an LED in such a way that the missing LED draws 5 mA? That doesn't make any sense. Either it is still there, or it is not there. If the removal shorted the pins then you would have a lot higher current drain than 5 mA.

Comment: @NickGammon I think that the problem is the SD card module because if I disconnect the CS, DI, DO and CK pins then the consumption is around the 60 uA.

Comment: @PinaGamer did you just disconnect those pins or also the VCC and GND pins of the SD card module? If you didn't, try leavinf those pins connected: if it is a module it should have an onboard converter and maybe a level shifter which remain powered (if it is the case, power it through an arduino pin and turn it off when not needed). If you only disconnected those pins and left VCC and GND connected, see with an oscilloscope if the status is changing. If it isn't, try measuring also the current sinked by the SD card (module) when in sleep

Comment: @frarugi87 I've only disconnected the pins that I mentioned above so VCC and GND remain connected. So do you recommend me remove the transistor and activate or deactivate the SD card module using a digital pin?

Comment: @PinaGamer what is the transistor you mentioned? I suggest you to 1) try measuring the current flowing in the SD module only when in sleep. 2) leave the SD module connected, but disconnect only VCC and measure the whole current. 3) post a link to the SD module you are using; maybe some other ideas can come.

Comment: @frarugi87 The consumption in your proposed cases are: 1) 4.8 mA 2) 3.9 mA. The SD card module is [this](https://www.elecfreaks.com/wiki/index.php?title=SD%26MMC_Card_Module_Double_Side).

Comment: Wait, you blocked the ground of the modules?? If so, try writing a HIGH value on all the SD card pins, not LOW (otherwise you are trying to power the device through the digital pins). And.. Consider using a PMOS instead to block the VCC pin...

Comment: digitalWrite(10, LOW) or better digitalWrite(10, HIGH) don't work if you don't disable SPI first.

Comment: @frarugi87 I don't understand why I need HIGH value instead of LOW value to switch off the SD card module. Why do I need a PMOS transistor?

Comment: @PinaGamer because if you switch off the transistor, every node on the SD should float up to VCC, the only remaining connection. If you apply a 0V on any pin, you put a differential voltage over the board, thus turning on something. Try with a high value (so everything is at VCC) or put the pins in high impedance (aka input mode). A PMOS transistor (or a PNP) is used to interrupt the VCC pin instead of the GND one, so you can keep the grounds together (it's usually a better approach, since usually grounds are designed to be together)

Comment: @Gerben Do you recommend me to put `digitalWrite(10, HIGH)` to enable the [internal PULL-UP](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/DigitalPins) of this pin? Why? With this statement current goes down to 80 uA.

Comment: See frarugi87's comment. Nothing to do with pull ups

Comment: @Gerben frarugi87 suggests me put the pins in high impedance so in `void setup()` I've put `digitalWrite(10, HIGH)`

Comment: `digitalWrite(10, HIGH)` doesn't mean high impedance. High impedance if when you change the pin to an INPUT. So `pinMode(10, INPUT)`. But I was referring to him saying you should set the pin to Vcc not GND. Also there is no point in doing this in `setup`. But please, re-read all the comments, cause I feel you are totally missing the points we are making.

Comment: If you considered your question answered, please accept an answer of post you own answer to close it.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION** [by OP]

My problem was that the SD card module was consuming when it was controlled by a transistor and my Arduino board was into the sleep mode. So I wrote into the `void setup()` the `digitalWrite(PIN, HIGH)` statements where PIN represents all pins connected to the board that belong to the SD card module (DI, DO, CS, and CK pins), to enable the internal resistor of that pins. Then, I checked the power consumption and I reached less than 100 uA.

Answer (score 0):

If you physically removed the LED make sure the pads for it aren't shorted together by old solder. If they aren't then you removed it correctly.

However: 5mA may be a perfectly reasonable current consumption for your project. Without seeing a full schematic and analysing your code it's impossible to say what kind of current you would expect to see.

Comment: I've upload a simple project like this: `#include <LowPower.h>
void setup(){
 LowPower.powerDown(SLEEP_TIME, ADC_OFF, BOD_OFF);
}
void loop(){
}`

And the consumption is a bit less than 3.5 mA. So I think that the code is not the problem

Comment: Like what? Also, how are you powering the board?

Comment: I power the project using 4 AA batteries with 1900 mAh.

Comment: TBH I'd be less worried about the 5mA consumption that I would be by the 30% power loss from the linear regulator. What else is connected to the board?

Comment: Interesting... I've isolated the board, I've measured again the current and now I'm getting 60 uA. So the problem is in the circuit... There are connected an SD card and GSM modules both controlled using transistors.

Comment: @PinaGamer If you remove power using a transistor, you must also make sure not the the SPI/UART pins are HIGH. Otherwise power will flow into the modules via this pin (and the clamping diodes in the modules ICs).

Comment: @Gerben I use `AltSoftSerial.h` [library](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_libs_AltSoftSerial.html) to communicate with the GSM module using digital pins 8 and 9 and pin 10 to begin the SPI communication with the SD card module but there is no any statement like `digitalWrite(8,HIGH)` or something like that.

Comment: @PinaGamer I'm not going to read all the library code to figure out if an output is set to HIGH while idle. You can do this yourself. Or you can do it the easy way, and while the arduino is sleeping, disconnect the modules, and use a multimeter to see if any of the output-pins that where connected to the modules read 5v. I recently did a project where I had to disable SPI and set the MOSI pin low, before powering down the device connected to the SPI bus.